# R create vector from specific matrix elements

Tags: r, vector, matrix

I'm using R to read some XML and convert it to something the `deSolve` library can work with. I'm trying to convert this matrix:

```
svars = xpathSApply(doc, "/models/model[@name='SIS']/state_variables/variable")
svars = sapply(svars, xmlAttrs)
svars

      [,1]          [,2]      
id    "S"           "I"       
name  "susceptible" "infected"
value "99"          "1"
```

To a vector that looks like this:

```
svars = c(S = 99, I = 1)
```

I'm a bit at a loss on how to do this, can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
dd <- svars[c("id","value"),]
setNames(dd$V2,dd$V3)
```

Or one linear :

```
setNames(as.numeric(svars["value", ]), svars["id",])
```

Comment: +1. Also `setNames(as.numeric(svars["value", ]), svars["id",])` works ;)

Comment: @Jilber! I hesitate to put this but finally I edit my answer.

Comment: @agstudy Your code did the trick, my code is a bit different:

  `state = as.vector(t(svars[value,]))`
  `if(forceNumeric){`
  `state = as.numeric(state)`
  `}`
  `names(state) = svars[name,]`

Answer (score 1):

I think following should do

```
x <- as.numeric(svars['value', ])
names(x) <- svars['id', ]
x
##  S  I 
## 99  1
```

which is same as

```
c(S = 99, I = 1)
##  S  I 
## 99  1
```